# How to set the Length and thickness of a Fabric Line?

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

This is my fabric line:

```
var newLine = new fabric.Line([120,100,120,300],{
        stroke: "#000000",
        strokeWidth: 2,
});
```

This is how I'm trying to set the thickness:

`newLine.setWidth(5);` and also `newLine.set('width', 5);`

Similarly I'm trying to set the length as:

`newLine.setHeight(250);` and also `newLine.set('width', 250);`

I am even calling `newLine.setCoords();` followed by `myCanvas.renderAll();`

What happens is that the line (which is currently vertical) becomes **tilted** (height and width remain unchanged). I checked the "angle" attribute of the object and its value is also unchanged.

What exactly is causing this to happen?
Alternatively, is there any way to set the length and thickness of a line without having to use its "x" and "y" coordinates?

P.S: I am using fabric JS version **0.9.15.min.js**.

Comment: You should be setting "strokeWidth" (http://fabricjs.com/docs/symbols/fabric.Object.html#strokeWidth) and changing width/height should change dimensions of a line. Just tested in kitchensink; works fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zzNW9/ can a bit help to you but set({... prop ....}) generates different result.